# Import Interface from Exported Typescript Namespace

Tags: typescript, typescript-namespace

I am using a third party library which exports interfaces inside namespaces in its `index.d.ts` file.

```
export namespace Ns {
  interface Foo {
    ...
  }

  interface Bar {
    ...
  }

export namespace AnotherNs {
  interface Foo {
    ...
  }

  interface Bar {
    ...
  }
```

How can I import the interfaces Foo from one of the namespace into my code?

Doing the following gives ts error `Cannot use namespace 'Ns' as a value.`

```
import { Ns } from "lib";

const foo: Ns.Foo = ...;
```